# How do i create a laravel 5 anywhere on my computer so that i can view the site on my browser

Tags: laravel, new-project

I am new to laravel and it is boring to keep creating projects in my htdocs folder drive C. Besides, i may lose all my projects if the operating system crashes. So is there a way i can create a laravel project anywhere in my computer so that i can be able to access it on my browser?
Thanks for help..

Comment: Putting it somewhere else on your computer won't save you from a disk failure. Get backups - Github, Dropbox, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can keep your laravel project anywhere in your computer. Even you can keep it in your external device like pen drive. Just run `php artisan serve` and you will be able to see your project at browser. Artisan command make this flexibility.
Just try it. Go to your laravel folder and run artisan command.